# Can I depart from my country 3 hours before my visa date but arrive on time at my destination?

Tags: visas, schengen-visas

I'm travelling from India to Germany on a student Visa.

I have booked my ticket to fly out of India on the 13th of September at 2050 IST. The visa is valid from 14.09.23 and the time of arrival at Germany is 0620 local time.
Since I have a layover at Abu Dhabi, I will only reach Germany after the commencement of my Visa date and not before it.
My question is whether I would be allowed to board the flight? (It's Etihad and I've not had a proper feedback on this from them)

Thanks in advance

Comment: It's certainly legal.  Whether the airline understands this is another matter, but it probably does.  Whether the staff members at the airport understand this is another matter still, and this is less certain.  There isn't much you can do about it at this point other than to call the airline for an advance indication of their policy and perhaps the name and number of a senior person to call if you run into trouble when you check in.